# Connecting a rails app to postgres via peer authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I'm setting up a simple rails app for my organization using postgres

#### User / Admin Setup

I have the following types of users set up

```
OS USER          POSTGRES USER       ASSOCIATED POSTGRES DB
postgres         postgres            postgres
user1            user1               
user2            user2               
.....            .....               .....
                 my_app              my_app
```

- **Postgres User** - default superuser
- **Various system users** - individual users in my company/organization that will be working with `my_app`.
- **App User** - An application user *in Postgres only*, which in turn owns a DB with the same name. There is no associated OS user.

#### Database YML file

```
development: &default
adapter: postgresql
database: my_app
encoding: utf8
host: localhost
min_messages: warning
pool: 2
timeout: 5000
```

#### Issues

Given the above, I'm running into the following -

1. Each user can not conveniently just type `psql` to enter the shell, because Postgres looks for a DB with the associated name, which doesn't exist. Is there a way to default it to use the `my_app` db? Or is there a way to enter the shell without having to specify a DB (similar to mySQL, where you select a DB after you log in) ?
2. On a new machine, the `my_app` database does not yet exist. I expect it to be created when running `rake db:create` as my own user, but I just receive `fe_sendauth: no password supplied`. Since it relies on peer authentication, do I have to have a corresponding OS user for `my_app`?
3. I also tried fixing the issue in #2 by actually adding in the `user:` and `password:` directly into `database.yml`. That only produced `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_app"`, although it's certainly the correct password.
4. Somewhat unrelated, but what does it mean when a postgres user "owns" a database? Can other users use and edit that database, or do they all have to log in as the owner to use it? (**EDIT**: This question is nicely answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29061/what-is-postgresql-database-ownership))

Thanks!